# How to allow Introspector.getBeans.getPropertyDescriptors() result in insertion order rather alphabetical order

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

I run the following to get Bean's fields and its values but I get the alphabetical order of property names.
Is there a way to get the order in which they can maintain the order in which bean has?

My Bean

```
@Component
public class FeedFile {

    private String pkey;
    private String omsOrderId;
    private String auctTitl;
    private String byrCntryId;
    private String lstgCurncyIsoCodeName;
    private String transSiteId;

    public String getPkey() {
        return pkey;
    }

    public void setPkey(String pkey) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
    }

    public String getOmsOrderId() {
        return omsOrderId;
    }

    public void setOmsOrderId(String omsOrderId) {
        this.omsOrderId = omsOrderId;
    }
    public String getAuctTitl() {
        return auctTitl;
    }

    public void setAuctTitl(String auctTitl) {
        this.auctTitl = auctTitl;
    }

    public String getByrCntryId() {
        return byrCntryId;
    }

    public void setByrCntryId(String byrCntryId) {
        this.byrCntryId = byrCntryId;
    }

    public String getLstgCurncyIsoCodeName() {
        return lstgCurncyIsoCodeName;
    }

    public void setLstgCurncyIsoCodeName(String lstgCurncyIsoCodeName) {
        this.lstgCurncyIsoCodeName = lstgCurncyIsoCodeName;
    }

    public String getTransSiteId() {
        return transSiteId;
    }

    public void setTransSiteId(String transSiteId) {
        this.transSiteId = transSiteId;
    }
```

Introspector code. Using `StringBuilder` to verify the order of `Introspector.getBeans.getPropertyDescriptors()` that returns in alphabetical order. It isn't related to hashmap random order in the result.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(file.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                String name = pd.getName();
                Object value = pd.getReadMethod().invoke(file);
                if ("class".equals(name)) continue;
                sb.append(name);
                sb.append(":");
                sb.append(value);
                sb.append(",");
                result.put(name, String.valueOf(value));
            }
```

Actual Output of the above in String Builder sb:

```
sb.toString()="auctTitl:Hello,byrCntryId:123,lstgCurncyIsoCodeName:USD,omsOrderId:234,pkey:567, transSiteId:987,";
```

Expected Output should be in the order of declaration of above bean `FeedFile`:

```
sb.toString()="pkey:567,omsOrderId:234,auctTitl:Hello,byrCntryId:123,lstgCurncyIsoCodeName:USD,transSiteId:987,";
```

I googled and found that Introspector only returns in alphabetical order. Is there any way I can get the expected output.

Comment: No.  Although you may see property descriptors returned in alphabetical order, that was never guaranteed.  And [the methods obtained by reflection are not guaranteed to be in any order.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods())  This is why there are annotation attributes like [XmlType.propOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#propOrder--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my above approach and this simplified it a lot.
I actually found a better way of doing this using `PrintWriter`, where my bean gets directly added to csv by overriding `toString()` in java bean. Here is what I did:

```
 public void writeToCsv(List<Sample> sampleList, String header) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filepath/demo/sample.csv");
        writer.println(header);

        for (Sample sample : sampleList) {
            writer.println(sample.toString());
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

Bean

```
class Sample {

  private String id;
  private String type;
  private String name;
  private int value;
  
  // getter-setter

  @Override
  public String toString(){
        StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        appendFieldValue(dataBuilder, id);
        appendFieldValue(dataBuilder, type);
        appendFieldValue(dataBuilder, name);
        appendFieldValue(dataBuilder, value);
        

        return dataBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void appendFieldValue(StringBuilder dataBuilder, String fieldValue) {
        if(fieldValue != null) {
            dataBuilder.append(fieldValue).append(",");
        } else {
            dataBuilder.append("").append(",");
        }
    }
}
```